# Laravel validate input to allow alphabets and spaces only

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a table based on input from a user from a form. I however want the user to be able to use alphabets and spaces characters in the form input. For example, the user might enter "sample table" or "table" but **not** "new table1". I tried using aplha validation but it doesn't work for empty spaces. What laravel rule handles this please?

Comment: `'regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/'`

Comment: @sta  ```regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/```  this regex always works for me !!

Answer (score 1):

****//This regex will work for laravel and accept only Alphabet A to Z and a to z and space and will not accept numeric value and other characters****

```
`$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'table' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s]+$/u|min:3',
    ]);`
```

Answer (score -2):

The proper way to define a validation rule should be:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
        'table' => 'regex:[a-zA-Z\s]+',
    ]);
```

Comment: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '+'